# Page generation time in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a login servlet that processes post request with username and password parameters, and does something like this:

```
    Instant pageGenStart = Instant.now();

    String username = req.getParameter("username");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");

    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

    User user = null;
    try {
        user = userService.getByUsername(username);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (user == null && !password.equals("")) {
        try {
            user = new User(username, password);
            user.setId(userService.addNewUser(username, password));

            charactersService.addNewCharacter(user);
            sessionsService.add(req.getSession().getId(), user.getId());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        Duration time = Duration.between(pageGenStart, Instant.now());

        resp.sendRedirect("/main");
    }
```

If user is not found in db, create new user and redirect him to main page. Normally i would just put this "time" variable into page, but i redirect my response to other servlet where doGet method is called. How do i let other servlet know how long login servlet took to proccess post request?

Comment: add it to your request or session

Comment: @ScaryWombat is there any method that would include it? or do i just add it as string like resp.sendRedirect("/main" + time.toMillis()) ? Because if i do that it doesn't get included as paramter.

Comment: What do you want to do with the time? In general, if you do an external redirect, you either need to store it in the session, or you include it in the request parameters of the redirect (but then you have to accept that it could be manipulated by the user, unless you sign the data)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt in general i just want to show page generation time on every page

Comment: `resp.sendRedirect("/main?generationTime=" + time.toMillis())`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thank you! i had a bit of problems because i was calling getAttribute(), not getParameter() in other servlet. Now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value from one servlet to another in many ways like :

1. Storing values in session ( You have to take care of session management)
2. Creating class having static ConcurrentHashMap and storing time gap per user session and fetching it using session ID. (same problem need to take care when to clear cache).
3. Use already defined lib ( best option as you need not to worry about session management and cache clear).

I perfer EH-cache for these kind of perposes you can see a good example from the [Link](https://www.mkyong.com/ehcache/ehcache-hello-world-example/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestuon! EH-cache is not quite what i look for in this project but i'll look into that later.